# Outputting the product atribute table within the product page (catalog/product/view.phtml)

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm attempting to place the product attribute table within a div on my product page, seperately from the content of the usual collateral tabs.
I've located the code from my attributes.phtml and i've tried to just copy and paste this code into the appropriate part of my view.phtml, resulting in the following:

```
<div class="spec-table">    
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
    <col width="25%" />
    <col />
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
        <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
        if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
 <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>

<?php endif;?>
</div>
```

When this didn't work, I tried invoking the attributes.phtml from within my view.phtml using:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

but sadly neither of these approaches seems to work, and I just end up with a blank div.
What's the best way to inject my attributes.phtml (or for that matter, the contents of any given .phtml file) into my product page at some arbitrary point?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this to work using the following

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view_attributes')->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```